# How can I use a customized build of the AWS sdk in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I make a customized build here of the AWS SDK:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/

I can't find any examples of how to use this in ReactJS.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I have tried putting this in my index.html

And in my ReactJS code replaced imoprt with var:

```
//import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
```

But now my application does not even load - shows only the background image and does not load - absolutely zero shows in the Chrome console - no messages at all.

[image: Nothing shown.]

I can see in the Chrome network console that the custom sdk build is being loaded OK with a status 200 so that seems to be OK.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import a customized build of AWS SDK as a module. You'll need to link it as an external js file in `/public/index.html`:

```
<script src="PATH/TO/YOUR/CUSTOM/aws-sdk-{SDK_VERSION}.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you can access the global variable `AWS` via `window` object:

```
const AWS = window.AWS;

AWS.config.region = "YOUR_BUCKET_REGION";
const bucket = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
  }
});
```

Alternatively, instead of linking to customized SDK builds, you can always `npm install aws-sdk` and then import individual AWS services as:

```
const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3");
```

Comment: I request you to have a look at my question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476748