# JS - use files meant for <script> in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I have used AWS's JS Builder (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) to generate a minified build of only their Lambda SDK. Now I want o use that in a  NodeJS-like (specifically ReactJS) environment.

Currently, I am doing so (after referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/49218103/1847976) by adding the said script in the `/public/index.html` and then accessing the main export (here: `AWS`) via the `window` object (as in here `window.AWS`).

However, are there any issues (specifically compatibility issues) I may face with such a workaround? If yes, is there a way I can directly use the minified JS obtained from AWS's JS Builder in ReactJS? Or is there a totally different method I could I have followed?

P.S.: I have already tried using the in-preview AWS SDK (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3) which will be modularised but faced un-fixable problems (due to which I posted another question here: [AWS JS SDK V3 (Lambda module) - Unable to connect to instance metadata service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472155/)), therefore that is ruled out. I also tried plainly adding the minifed (and unminified) file directly in my React project and importing it but that didn't work either

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do in ReactJS? Can you complement your answer with concrete code examples and the errors that resulted from such attempts?

Comment: As stated, I'm trying to "natively" use a JS file generated by AWS's JS Builder which is meant for the html ```<script>``` tag, but it isn't working